# Setting Counter value specific to an id column based on an input chunk value in teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I have a table having the below data distribution :

```
cola colb 
id1     a
id1     b
id2     c
id2     d
id3     e
id3     f
id4     g
id4     h
```

I am trying to create an additional id field based on a chunk value which I will be passing as input : for eg 2 in this case. So, my end result would look something like this :

```
cola colb col_new_id
id1     a        1
id1     b        1
id2     c        1
id2     d        1
id3     e        2
id3     f        2
id4     g        2
id4     h        2
```

Is there a way to handle it using window/analytical functions in teradata. We can always loop and generate the value of col3 based on col1 values, but I am looking for a query level solution without looping. Will it be possible.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `col_new_id` is being generated, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: col_new_id will be generated by clubbing the id values in col1. For eg, in my example the clubbing factor is 2, so two ids id1 and id2 are clubbed together across col_new_id , the value of which is 1. The clubbing factor will belike an input to the query. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` over the `cola` values to generate a number which represents the order of that value in the list then add `chunk - 1` and integer divide by `chunk` to create the `col_new_id` value. For example:

```
DECLARE @chunk INT;
SET @chunk = 2;
SELECT cola, colb, 
       (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cola) + @chunk - 1) / @chunk AS col_new_id
FROM data
```

Output:

```
cola    colb    col_new_id
id1     a       1
id1     b       1
id2     c       1
id2     d       1
id3     e       2
id3     f       2
id4     g       2
id4     h       2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e7c5d4b098d0c9f1947d7630c820aba0)

Comment: superb. Thanks @Nick

Comment: Slight simplification: `(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cola) - 1) / @chunk + 1 AS col_new_id`

Comment: @dnoeth six of one, half a dozen of another, you're just moving the add from inside the parentheses (`+ @chunk`) to outside (`+ 1`).

Comment: Of course. But as Teradata doesn't support parameters outside of Stored Procedures my version just needs to specify the chunksize once :-)